# move the block of compare products from right to footer page

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, frontend

i'm new in Magento world and a few minutes ago i had an error.
I'm trying to apply a modify in catalog.xml file: move the block of compare products from right to footer page.
For test i trying to move the line:

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

in footer section of page.xml file (this is stupid, but i wanted to try :) );
and after this, the frontend is disappear, page white.
I enabled the log in backend and the log file report this:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &quot; as =&quot;global_cookie_notice&quot; template=&quot;page/html/cookienotice.phtml&quot; before=&quot;-&quot;   in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

and this:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 112: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag block line 112  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

Someone can i help me?
Thank you! :) :)

Comment: You have messed up the XML in the layout file. Revert your changes, clear cache and refresh page.

Comment: @ParasSood you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

in rwd theme  compare should look like

change this

```
<reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">-->
                <!--<action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_right_callout.jpg</src></action>-->
                <!--<action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Keep your eyes open for our special Back to School items and save A LOT!</alt></action>-->
            <!--</block>-->
        </reference>
```

to

```
<reference name="footer">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar"  name="catalog.compare.footer" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>

        </reference>
```

if this code is not work then 
add a extra code in

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.compare.footer')?>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to resolve my problem, but i resolve it with a new installation of Magento :)

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up the XML in the layout file. Revert your changes, clear cache and refresh page.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i revert the changes, the cache is disable, i clean the browser cache but is still not working. I resolve with a new installation of Magento. Thank you another time for trying to help me :) –